# Сохранение оригинального название файла, после загрузки файла на сервер

Tags: php

Есть код, который загружает файл в папку

```
if($_FILES){
    if(isset($_FILES)){
        $testName = $_FILES['test']['name'];
    }
    else{
        $testName = '';
    }

    if(empty($testName)){
        echo 'Згрузите тест';
    }

    echo $testName;

    $testTmpFileName = isset($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['test']['tmp_name'] : '';

    if($testTmpFileName){
        $exploded = explode('.', $testName); //разделил строку на массив и последний элемент оказался расширением

        $testFileName = './test/'. md5($testName) . '.' . array_pop($exploded); //путь картинки
        $successMoved = move_uploaded_file($testTmpFileName, $testFileName); //перемещаю файл
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Вот допустим, если загрузить файл test.json
то он загрузится и название у него будет
29f2371dad30835b344a6ca05b473eae.json

А сделать, что бы название было такое же test.json?

Comment: Почему так не работает? $successMoved = rename(move_uploaded_file($testTmpFileName, $testFileName), $testName);

Answer (score 1):

Никто не запрещает взять имя файла из `$_FILES['test']['name']`. Ведь оригинальное имя там и хранится.

```
$uploaddir = 'путь/к/директории/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['test']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)
```

Comment: Поддерживаю, но предупреждаю топик-стартера, что сохранение файла с оригинальным именем приведет к прыжкам по граблям, связанным с тем, что в Windows и Linux используются различные кодировки. Поэтому, если есть возможность избежать сохранения файлов с оригинальным именем - избегайте этого. Гораздо лучше сохранять оригинальное имя в БД, а на диске хранить файлы с нормализованными именами. Когда понадобится отдавать файл обратно, прочитаете оригинальное имя из БД и установите его с помощью `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file original name.XXX"');`.